# how to take input for uint32_t variable

Tags: uint32

i have declared a variable as
uint32_t num;
when i take input for this variable i.e
cin>>num;
cout<

when i run this program, i gives num value as 12345678, it works fine & give cout. but when i give input as 1234abcd. it creates problem & displays only 1234.
please suggest solution to resolve this problem.

Answer (score 2):

Use `std:: cin >> std::hex >> num;` if you want to read hex numbers.